# Best way to dump one database table with limit and all association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, mysql, dump

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :friends, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I need smth like this:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 1000" -uroot development profiles  > profiles.sql
```

But this dump contains (as expected) only  1000 profiles rows, without associations friends, favorites.

Should I do it using YAML or how should I do it?

Comment: dump all three tables, then delete profiles with id > 1000

Comment: I think it is bad idea, because I have over 18 millions records

Comment: how about a script that finds the primary keys for all favorites/friends linked to the first 1000 users, then you can do a separate dump for those table specifying those primary keys

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take first 5000 records:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 5000" -uroot development profiles  > profiles.sql
```

Then find all associated with this records friends:

```
mysqldump --opt --lock-all-tables --where="profile_id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM profiles LIMIT 5000) temp);" -uroot development friends  > friends.sql
```